# React-Native Todo list not adding new item after text input and button press

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am so confused, I have nowhere else to turn. I am having trouble working on a todo app in expo. All I need to do is add the functionality to when you input text in the text box and press the button, it adds an item onto the list.

This is all of my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, FlatList, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
import {Card, CheckBox, Button} from 'react-native-elements';


export default function App() {
  const [addListItem, OnChangeText] = React.useState("Insert new Item")
  
  function addTodoItem() {
    React.setState(prevState => ({
      data: [...prevState.data, 
      {completed: false, description: <TextInput/>, key: prevState.curKey}],
      curKey:prevState.curKey+1
    }))
  } 
  let [data, setData] = React.useState( 
  [
    {
      key: "1",
      description: "Do Dishes",
      completed: false
    },
    {
      key: "2",
      description: "Clean Living Room",
      completed: false
    },
  ])

  let renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return <>
      <CheckBox 
        center
        title={item.description}
        checked={item.completed}
        onPress={() => {

          let newData = [...data]
          let itemToLookFor = newData.find((item2) => item.key == item2.key)
          itemToLookFor.completed = !itemToLookFor.completed
          setData(newData)
        }}
        textStyle={item.completed ? {textDecoration: "line-through"} : undefined}
      />
    </>
  }

/* addTodoItem = () => {

} */

  return (
    <View>
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Card>
        <Card.Title>TODO APP</Card.Title>
        <Card.Divider/>
         <FlatList data={data} renderItem={renderItem}></FlatList>
        <Card.Divider/>
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={OnChangeText}
          value={addListItem}
        />
        <Button
          title="+"
          onPress={addTodoItem()}
        />
      </Card>
    </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    color: 'darkred',
  }
});
```

any help would be much appreciated, I am relatively new to React, so the answer is probably something simple.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are a few issues in the example. I will go through them one by one. You can also find a working snack here: https://snack.expo.io/@mlisik/6640ff

1. `React.setState` -- this hook does not exist. Is it something custom you import or define somewhere else? You likely want to rewrite your `addTodoItem` to use `setData` instead:

```
const addTodoItem = React.useCallback(() => {
  setData(prevData => [
    ...prevData,
    {
      key: `${prevData.count}`,
      description: addListItem,
      completed: false
    }
  ]);
}, [addListItem, setData]);
```

2. Pass `addToDoItem` to your Button without calling it:

```
<Button
  title="+"
  onPress={addTodoItem}
/>
```

When you pass `addTodoItem()` you are passing the return value of calling the function, which isn't what you want.

3. Cosmetic - instead of using "Insert new Item" as the initial value for `addListItem`, set it as a placeholder for your text field:

```
const [addListItem, OnChangeText] = React.useState("")
...
<TextInput
  onChangeText={OnChangeText}
  placeholder="Insert new Item"
  value={addListItem}
/>
```

You will then also want to clear `addListItem` in your `addTodoItem` callback:

```
  OnChangeText("");
```